# add new node/column to xml/xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display the node value for Student Name but it is displaying the node name and the value in a new row. Am I missing anything here?

Here is my XML:

```
<StudentRequest Template="StudentRequestResultTabular.xslt" Description="Student Lookup">
  <Student Type="Grade" Value="Freshmen1">
    <STDUID>171TR</STDUID>
    <SHNAME>Tom Riley</SHNAME>
  </Student>
  <Student Type="Grade" Value="Freshmen2">
    <STDUID>164SR</STDUID>
    <SHNAME>Sean Ryan</SHNAME>
  </Student>
  <Student Type="Grade" Value="Sophomore1">
    <STDSID>210JM</STDSID>
    <SHNAME>July Middleton</SHNAME>
  </Student>
  <Student Type="Grade" Value="Senior1">
    <STDSID>252JD</STDSID>
    <SHNAME>Jack Deer</SHNAME>
  </Student>
  <Student Type="Grade" Value="Junior1">
    <STDRID>350JB</STDRID>
    <SHNAME>John Barb</SHNAME>
  </Student>
</StudentRequest>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="StudentRequest" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="StudentRequest">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Student Grade</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>ID Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Student" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Student">
    <xsl:variable name="StudentGrade">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="*">     
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$StudentGrade"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="StudentRequest/Student/SHNAME"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output:

```
StudentGrade Student Name  ID Type  Value 
  Freshmen1                STDUID   171TR
  Freshmen1                SHNAME   Tom Riley
  Freshmen2                STDUID   164SR
  Freshmen2                SHNAME   Sean Ryan
  Sophomore1               STDSID   210JM
  Sophomore1               SHNAME   July Smith
  Senior1                  STDSID   252JD
  Senior1                  SHNAME   Jack Deer
  Junior1                  STDRID   350JB
  Junior1                  SHNAME   John Barb
```

Required output:

```
StudentGrade  Student Name  ID Type  Value 
  Freshmen1   Tom Riley     STDUID   171TR
  Freshmen2   Sean Ryan     STDUID   164SR
  Sophomore1  July Smith    STDSID   210JM
  Senior1     Jack Deer     STDSID   252JD
  Junior1     John Barb     STDRID   350JB
```

Comment: Why is Tom Riley's record wrapper `Student`, while all others are `StudentID`? And why does each student's ID have a different element name? Are you sure that's how the real document is organized?

Comment: @michael.hor257k updated record wrapper's to 'Student' for all. Student ID's are of different type, thats why they have different element names. I am displaying the ID Type as a column because it could have different ID Types

Comment: Now that you have edited the question, it is no longer true that the stylesheet you show yields the output you show.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I updated the xslt to reflect xml template name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>StudentGrade</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>ID Type</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="StudentRequest/Student" />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Student">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SHNAME"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name(*[1])"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively (and preferably), if you know all the possible variations of the ID type, use:

```
<xsl:template match="Student">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SHNAME"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name(STDUID | STDSID | STDRID)"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="STDUID | STDSID | STDRID"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: My bad! I didnt notice I had StudentID as the first column. It is Student Grade and it is a variable in the template

Comment: Well, that's easy to fix (and you don't need the variable).

Answer (score 2):

Having a template that matches `StudentID` is the right thing, but then, the name of the student is not really in `@Value`, so the following variable from your original code does not make much sense:

```
<xsl:variable name="StudentName">
  <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Instead, the name of the student is inside the `SHNAME` element. Also, there is no need for an `xsl:for-each` to loop through the child elements of `StudentID` - just do away with it.

Since you apparently cannot be sure whether a `StudentID` element has a child `STDUID` or `STDSID`, use an XPath expression that reflects this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'STD')]"/>
```

As a last note, I am not sure if it makes much sense to have the student ID appear in both the first and the last cell of a row. Is this the behaviour you need?

**XSLT 1.0 Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="StudentRequest">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Student Grade</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>ID Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="StudentID|Student">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="SHNAME"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name(*[starts-with(local-name(),'STD')])"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'STD')]"/></td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

Note that the HTML output is not a complete HTML document, only a fragment.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Student Grade</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>ID Type</th>
      <th>Value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Freshmen</td>
      <td>Tom Riley</td>
      <td>STDUID</td>
      <td>171TR</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Freshmen</td>
      <td>Sean Ryan</td>
      <td>STDUID</td>
      <td>164SR</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Sophomore</td>
      <td>July Middleton</td>
      <td>STDSID</td>
      <td>210JM</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Senior</td>
      <td>Jack Deer</td>
      <td>STDSID</td>
      <td>252JD</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Junior</td>
      <td>John Barb</td>
      <td>STDRID</td>
      <td>350JB</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Rendered Output (Firefox, now updated)**

> [image]

Comment: `*[starts-with(local-name(),'STD')]/local-name()` is not XPath 1.0.

Comment: @JLRishe You are right, thanks for pointing it out! I was accidentally testing with Saxon 9.5. I have amended my answer.

Comment: @MathiasMüller My bad! I didnt notice I had StudentID as the first column. It is Student Grade and it is a variable in the template

Comment: @user793468 I have edited my answer - please have another look at the HTML output. Is it correct now?